# How to do performance tuning in production cluster for spark job?

Tags: apache-spark

Lets assume we have a spark job where we are doing all the performance tuning and making it to run of development environment which is going to have limited configuration (1 node 32GB RAM 500GB Hard disk)

Obviously our production cluster is going to be high, how the tuning parameters which measured in development environment can be helpful in production cluster. Is it advisable to tune jobs directly in production cluster ? 
How it is being done in real-time ?

Comment: Performance tuning in the code, configuration level or both? Example: Code level would be improvements using broadcast join while configuration would be optimizing executor size

Comment: In both levels because obviously even in code level we will play with small data set in development environment.  For example, Repartitioning is not the same in Dev and prod ..

Comment: I can't speak for every company in the world, but in the ones were I worked, distributed jobs (MapReduce, spark, or others) could always fail because of scalability that were only visible in prod.
For that reason (and also for prod data investigation), cluster resources were allocated to run 'dev' jobs on the prod cluster.
Of course, ideally you might want to find ways to reproduce the same issues on smaller volumes to investigate in preprod. But that is not always possible. 
This means that our prod jobs incorporate lots of metrics and monitoring to help pinpoint problems when they happen.

Answer (score 1):

Shameless Plug (Author) try Sparklens https://github.com/qubole/sparklens Most of the time the real question is not if the application is slow, but will it scale. And for most of the applications, answer is upto a limit.

The structure of spark application puts important constraints on its scalability. Number of tasks in a stage, dependencies between stages, skew and amount of work done on the driver side are the main constraints.

One of the best features of Sparklens is that it simulates and tell you how your spark application will perform with different executor counts. Looks perfect for your problem.